# MFC decompile to any code not assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, mfc, decompiling, decompiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a C++ decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205059/is-there-a-c-decompiler)
>   [Is there a decompiler that will work on Visual Studio 6 C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928318/is-there-a-decompiler-that-will-work-on-visual-studio-6-c)

I need any way to decompile exe file which written in MFC, I tried IDA Pro, but it convert the file into assembly and no so good, because it has a lot of question marks characters.
If the directly converting file in to code is impossible, is there any way to convert assembly to C++? :(

thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. The compliation process destroys all metadata, including variable names, and the optimisation process makes it difficult to recover even a pseudocode replica of the original source.

Here's a highly simplified example. Let's say you write "foo++", where foo is an int. Depending on the compiler, this could compile to any of the following:

- `inc dword ptr [esp+12h]` - foo is kept as a local on the stack
- `inc dword ptr [00000f00h]` - foo is a heap variable
- `add dword ptr [00000f00h], 1` - another way to increment
- `mov eax, dword ptr [esp+12h]; inc eax` - move from the stack in to eax, then increment
- etc...

The possibilities are practically endless.

Your best bet is to look into something like Hex-Rays Decompiler, though it isn't cheap. It works with IDA to produce pseudo-C code, which you can use to discover how particular functions and routines work.

Comment: Also take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273145/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-windows-exe-or-at-least-view-the-assembly

Comment: which option I must choose in : new assembly database panel ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What software are you using? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am using IDA pro, I am trying to work as you said "Hex-Rays Decompiler"
but I don't know which option must I select when i create new project in IDA pro

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what you're specifically trying to do with it. When you purchased Hex-Rays, you were given details on how to contact support. You should go talk to them - might as well get your money's worth, considering the €1721 you just spent!